# How can a non-linear temperature resistance characteristics be a problem in sensors

Tags: sensor, temperature

When thinking about signal conversion in temperature sensors how could the non-linear temperature-resistance characteristics be a problem ?

Comment: A problem in what sense? It is of course a problem if you expect a linear relation!

Comment: For what application? What sensor? non-linear sensors are a pain if you want to implement a feed-back loop.

Comment: I'm learning about temperature sensors. When taking account of signal conversion how could that be problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with very nonlinear sensors such as thermistors is that the resolution (or SNR if analog) at temperature extremes may be insufficient with normal signal conditioning.

For example a 10K thermistor might change 450 ohms for one degree at 25 C but less than 5 ohms for 1 degree C at 150 C.

This is not a problem with most other types sensors at non-cryogenic temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

Not such a problem at all, you can compute the corrected temperature with a polynomial equation. The real problem is to make a good PCB layout for ADC, and good ADC like TI's ADS1248.
   